# React Native multiple "Root" Views?

Tags: react-native, navigation

Building my first React Native Application.

Currently I am using this way of navigating through different views.

```
<NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name={"Start"} component={Welcome}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"LoginMethod"} component={LoginMethod}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"SocialSecurityNumber"} component={SocialSecurityNumber}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"NorBankId"} component={NorBankId}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"NorBankIdMobile"} component={NorBankIdMobile}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"NorBankIdMobileUsername"} component={NorBankIdMobileUsername}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"NorBankIdMobilePassword"} component={NorBankIdMobilePassword}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"Fingerprint"} component={Fingerprint}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={"MainView"} component={MainView}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

This setup, is for the onboarding process from a new customer.

So the first component is `Welcome` and then the user moves along, with the option to go backwards.

However, when they are done with the process (the last screen), I want them to arrive to a "Screen" that is not ontop of the Stack, but it's own "Root" or "Base" View.

**What I have looked into**

I have tried having multiple stack navigators which is a no no. Also checked the `Tab` navigator, however this creates a tab menu below me screen, which I do not want.

Is it possible to do what I want, or do I need to restructure the way I have my setup now?

Thank you for your time, Stay Safe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't want to use multiple Stack-Navigators?

My approach would be:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
    { inWelcomeProcess && <WelcomeNavigator/>}
    <AuthNavigator/>
</NavigationContainer>
```

```js
const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();

export const AuthNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <AuthStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
           <AuthStackNavigator.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthScreen} options={authScreenOptions}/>
           // Your other screens (after finishing the on-boarding) should go here
        </AuthStackNavigator.Navigator>
        );
    };

const WelcomeStackNavigator= createStackNavigator();

export const WelcomeNavigator= () => {
    return (
        <WelcomeStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
            // Your On-Boarding process screens here
        </WelcomeStackNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Comment: Ah, i did not know that was possible to have multiple, I tried it once but got an error, must've tried it incorrectly. I will try this out soon, Thank you for your reply!